# What should go in world.launch file?

Tags: file, ubuntu, ros, launch, gazebo-simu

[https://pixllab.github.io/URSDocumentation/welcome/notes/2020/11/15/Gazebo-Map-Making.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I don't know what world.launch in number 9 of the homepage above means and what it contains. If anyone knows about this, please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch file you are looking for is located, as mentioned, in the launch directory, and it github you can find it in here:
https://github.com/PIxLLab/URSSimEnvironments/blob/master/urs_wearable/launch/world.launch